# What is the purpose of <!--suppress ALL --> in Android XML file?

Tags: xml, android-studio

The warnings come again and again into XML file of google Map, but when I use `<!--suppress ALL-->` all the warning are disabled. So what are the benefits of suppress all comment ?

```
<!--suppress ALL-->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlMapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width=`enter code here`"match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<!--suppress ALL-->` is a fairly drastic way to say "Dear linter, please don't mark *anything* I'm writing here as invalid - leave it all alone."

The benefits of this are mixed at best, but it can be advantageous if you're absolutely sure you're writing XML that doesn't need to be validated, or XML you choose not to validate in the first place.

That being said, it's not an advisable decision to use this unless you're absolutely sure there's nothing you can do about them, as bulk ignoring all warnings is a great way to get yourself into trouble later on.

Comment: Thank you so much :) i understand your suggestions. It sounds good.